# Java Web Start Unable to load db2jcc.jar

Tags: java, db2, jnlp, java-web-start, securityexception

I have signed every jar required by the application but when trying to launch, it produces following exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver" does not match trust level of other classes in the same package
at com.sun.deploy.security.CPCallbackHandler$ChildElement.checkResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.checkResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jnlp.JNLPClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.nzna.shared.db.DatabaseSystem.<init>(DatabaseSystem.java:193)
at com.ibm.nzna.projects.qit.Qit.run(Qit.java:556)
at com.ibm.nzna.projects.qit.Qit.<init>(Qit.java:185)
at com.ibm.nzna.projects.qit.Qit.main(Qit.java:123)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have signed the `db2jcc.jar` also. Could any one please help me with this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680823/java-lang-securityexception-class-org-apache-log4j-logger-does-not-match-trus) that deals with the error message.

There's also this information from a [security bulletin](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html),

> The following two SecurityExceptions are thrown after mixed components
>   had previously been detected and a decision was made to allow them to
>   coexist. The exceptions indicate that a component name collision
>   (resource name or class package name) was detected between trusted and
>   untrusted components and the request to load the resource or class was
>   denied.
>
> "resource \"" + name + "\" does not match trust level of other
>   resources of the same name" "class
>
> \"" + packageName + "\" does not
>   match trust level of other classes in the same package"

Answer (score 0):

Check this out https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6967414 It may be the cause of your problem.